# Are there any unique features provided only by metaclasses in Python?

Tags: python, oop, metaclass, python-datamodel

I have read answers for this question: [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) and this question: [In Python, when should I use a meta class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361181/in-python-when-should-i-use-a-meta-class) and skimmed through documentation: [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

It is very possible I missed something, and I would like to clarify: is there anything that metaclasses can do that cannot be properly or improperly (unpythonic, etc) done with the help of other tools (decorators, inheritance, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bit tricky to answer -
However, it is a very nice question to ask at this point, and there are certainly a few things that are *easier* to do with metaclasses.

So, first, I think it is important to note the things for which one used to need a metaclass in the past, and no longer needs to: I'd say that with the release of Python 3.6 and the inclusion of `__init_subclass__` and `__set_name__` dunder methods, a lot, maybe the majority of the cases I had always written a metaclass for (most of them for answering questions or in toy code - no one creates that many production-code metaclasses even in a lifetime as a programmer) became outdated.

Specially `__init_subclass__` adds the convenience of being able to transform any attribute or method like class-decorators, but is automatically applied on inheritance, which does not happen with decorators.
I guess reading about it was a fator motivating your question - since most metaclasses found out in the wild deal with transforming these attributes in `__new__` and `__init__`  metaclass methods.

However, note that if one needs to transform any attribute *prior* to having it included in the class, the metaclass `__new__` method is the only place it can be done. In most cases, however, one can simply transform it in the final new class namespace.

Then, one version forward, in 3.7, we had `__class_getitem__` implemented - since using the `[ ]` (`__getitem__`) operator directly on classes became popular due to typing annotations. Before that, one would have to create a metaclass with a `__getitem__` method for the sole purpose of being able to indicate to the type-checker toolchain some extra information like generic variables.

One interesting possibility that did not exist in Python 2, was introduced in Python 3, then outdated, and now can only serve very specific cases is the use of the `__prepare__` method on the metaclass:
I don't know if this is written in any official docs, but the obvious primary motivation for metaclass `__prepare__` which allows one custom namespace for the class body, was to return an ordered dict, so that one could have ordered attributes in classes that would work as data entities. It turns out that also, from Python 3.6 on, class body namespaces where always ordered (which later on Python 3.7 were formalized for all Python dictionaries). However, although not needed for returning an `OrderedDict` anymore, `__prepare__` is still aunique thing in the language in which it allows a custom mapping class to be used as namespace in a piece of Python code (even if that is limited to class bodies). For example, one can trivialy create an "auto-enumeration" metaclass by returning a

```
class MD(dict):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
       super().__init__(*args, **kw)
       self.counter = 0
   def __missing__(self, key):
       counter = self[key] = self.counter
       self.counter += 1
       return counter


class MC(type):
   @classmethod
   def __prepare__(mcls, name, bases, **kwd):
       return MD()

class Colors(metaclass=MC):
   RED
   GREEN
   BLUE
```

(an example similar to this is included in Luciano Ramalho's 'Fluent Python' 2nd edition)

The `__call__` method on the metaclass is also peculiar: it control the calls to `__new__` and `__init__` whenever an instance of the class is created. There are recipes around that use this to create a "singleton" - I find those terrible and overkill: if I need a singleton, I just create an instance of the singleton class at module level. However, overriding `typing.__call__` offers a level of control on class instantiation that may be hard to achieve on the class `__new__` and `__init__` themselves. But this definitely **can** be done by correctly keeping the desired states in the class object itself.

`__subclasscheck__` and `__instancecheck__`: these are metaclass only methods, and the only workaround would be to make a class decorator that would re-create a class object so that it would be a "real" subclass of the intended base class. (and that is not always possible).

"hidden" class attributes: now, this can be useful, and is less known, as it derives from the language behavior itself: any attribute or method besides the `dunder` methods included in a metaclass can be used from a *class*, but from *instances* of that class. An example for this is the `.register` method in classes using `abc.ABCMeta`. This contrasts with ordinary classmethods which can be used normally from an instance.

And finally, any behavior defined with the dunder methods for a Python object can be implemented to work on classes if they are defined in the metaclass. So if you have any use case for "add-able" classes, or want a special `repr` for your classes, just implement `__add__` or `__repr__` on the metaclass: this behavior obviously can't be obtained by other means.

I think I got all covered there.